# Reload jApplet in browser dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, java-native-interface

I have created a applet which use a library which indirectly calls some native code which loads dll but some how java cannot unloadnow the dll so i managed to kill the applet itself
but after killing, applet wont load on refresh event of java script

i am currently using signed applet

The problem is in native library itself SUN recognize it as a medium state bug in java (as per SUN manual Java Bugs https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5075039 )

Exception in thread "Thread-30" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library C:\Users\Mandar.jssc\windows\jSSC-0.9_x86.dll already loaded in another classloader
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)